# Spring + Hibernate = "manual" transactions how-to

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, transactions

My webapp (Spring3 + Hibernate3) always worked with services class-annotated with **@Transactional** and this configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Now... I'm on Google AppEngine. For some nasty reason I don't know yet, @Transactional does not work. It uses some class in javax.naming, which is not whitelisted. It ends up with:

> Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory': Post-processing of
>   the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl

Please don't ask me why....  :-\

Using Spring's HibernateTemplate instead of my dao (which uses raw session factory) solved the problem, but I know it's a little obsolete.

So, I want to try using manual old style transactions. Questions:

- where? I'd like to keep the transactions in the service layer.
- how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SessionFactoryImpl` dependency is not in Google App Engine whitelist. There is a number of Google hits discussing it.

As far as "what to do", you have options:

- Depend on on another JPA provider
- Don't use ORM at all, and go native with Spring's JdbcTemplate (my favorite)
- I am not sure why you need to use a programmatic transaction management since Hibernate is the root of your problem, but if you just like to know how, here is a draft:

```
public class SomeService implements SomeInterface {

   private SomeDao thisDaoWrapsJdbcTemplate;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   public void setTransactionManager( PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager ) {
      this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
   }

   public void doBusiness( Business: business ) {

      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction( def );

      try {

         // do business here
         Money money = Money.LOTS_OF
         ...
         // wire the money in..
         thisDaoWrapsJdbcTemplate.depositLotsOfMoney( money )

         transactionManager.commit( status );

      } catch ( DataAccessException dae ) {

         transactionManager.rollback( status );
         throw dae;
      }
      return;
   }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. Can you point me the right place in Hibernate docs for this (or a quick tutorial about that argument)? I will answer in next comments to your questions:

Comment: 1 and 2) another JPA provider... what do you mean? I am using Google Cloud SQL. My GAE application could use native JDBC but.... I like ORMs, and Hibernate is very attractive. Do you mean using JPA instead of Hibernate?

Comment: 3) I need to use programmatic transactions because @Transactional (don't know why) depends on javax.naming in some part. I also tried using declarative <aop> (aspectj) tx configuration but.... same exception! Class not found: javax.naming.NamingException. And nobody in the GAE team is helping me! :-( Now, with your help, my DAO is working again!

Comment: given the 3rd comment (e.g. `DAO is working again`), not sure whether you need the answer to a comment above, but here it comes: by another JPA provider I meant guys like Kodo, EclipseLink, DataNucleus, OpenJPA, etc. But since you already got `yours` to work, this info is for theoretical purposes only.

Comment: since you're so kind, I ask you: how can I remove duplication if I want to use your example in my services? I mean, can I write the "transaction wrapping code" in one place, then pass my action code inside it? I understand if you understood nothing.

Comment: you can pass a callback/function/etc.. into "doBusiness" method above: e.g. `public void doBusiness( Business: business, YourService: service ) { ... try { service.someMethod( business ); tx.commit(status) } ... }`. This way you can reuse your transaction logic that would live in one place.

Comment: I do not understand how but thank you however. Consider editing your answer with that code to get more points.