# JPA transactions with less pain without Guice/Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, osgi, guice

Both Spring and Guice-persist allow `@Transactional` annotation on methods accessing the database to automatically create transaction if one isn't open, commit it on method return, rollback on exception, etc.

Are there ways to get the same thing (or similarly usable) without using Spring or Guice in an OSGi application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Aries allows you to configure transactions declaratively in your blueprint.xml. For example:

```
<blueprint
xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

<bean
    id="transactedBean"
    class="some.package.BeanImpl">
    <tx:transaction
        method="*"
        value="Required" />
```

The Aries bundles can be dropped in an OSGi framework of your choice.

Comment: Too bad Aries Blueprint Annotations aren't mature yet :( But it's a good option, since I am using Karaf (and so Aries) anyway.

Comment: To clarify: does this make all public methods transactional, or all methods independent of visibility?

Answer (score 4):

I've got the following snippet of code that I use fairly often even when running in a Guice/Spring @Transactional container:

```
public void transact(Runnable runnable) {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    boolean success = false;
    tx.begin();
    try {
        runnable.run();
        success = true;
    } finally {
        if (success) {
            tx.commit();
        } else {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}

public <T> T transact(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    boolean success = false;
    tx.begin();
    try {
        T result = callable.call();
        success = true;
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (success) {
            tx.commit();
        } else {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dao.transact(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do stuff in JPA
    }
});

Long count = dao.transact(new Callable<Long>() {
    public Long call() {
        return em.createQuery("select count(*) from Foo", Long.class)
            .getSingleResult();
    }
});
```

Its very lightweight and gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use Spring Data JPA, as it [can be used outside Spring container](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.standalone) with [`JpaRepositoryFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.html) as your `RepositoryFactorySupport`. Useful information on getting this working is in [How do you use Spring Data JPA outside of a Spring Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123964/how-do-you-use-spring-data-jpa-outside-of-a-spring-container).

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at the problem differently, and instead of thinking of how exactly to implement transactional plumbing, think about *something wrapped in a transaction*, where a `transaction` is just a wrapper that does not really mean much **until** committed.

This word may sound weird and scares many devs away, but it *does* make a lot of sense.. talking about a Monad here, or better yet a...

### Transactional Monad

```
trait Transactional[A] {
  def map[B]( f: A => B): Transactional[B]
  def flatMap[B]( f: A => Transactional[B] ): Transactional[B]
}
```

Here is a [post](http://advorkovyy.blogspot.com/2010/10/transactional-monad-for-scala.html) that discusses the approach, but the gist is to apply functions freely without any side effects (e.g. within a transaction, e.g. it always just wraps all the function outputs in `Transactional`) **until** you are ready to commit, and then you call a "commit" (a.k.a `unsafePerformIO`) to actually "change the universe".

The above is in Scala, and maybe Monad may not be something extremely obvious or desirable at first, but it is just a different way of looking at the problem => e.g. no frameworks, AOP, mutations, etc.. just pure function composition (FTW!)

Comment: Well, it doesn't scare _me_ away. However, I also need the solution to be usable in Java, and that would be extremely verbose.

Comment: can you throw a `scala.jar` in the mix, and just treat it as you do `log4j` and others. e.g. "just a lib"?

Comment: if you absolutely must use Java, take a look at a [Manual Transactions How To](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939462/spring-hibernate-manual-transactions-how-to/9953098#9953098), which you can implement to actually take a `callback`/function that would be wrapped within a transaction. But, again, throwing a `scala.jar` as just another lib can't be all that bad, and you get to use the composition way, which makes a bit more sense.

Comment: I am talking about how calls from Java would look: `flatMap(new Function1<A, Transactional<B>> { @Override public Transactional<B> apply(A arg) { ... } })` etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, it can be simplified, but not _that_ much.